# rails order by undefined attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a situation where I need to add phones to an user, models are:

```rb
User
    attr_accessible :name
    has_many :phones

Phone
    attr_accesible :number, :type, :user_id
    belongs_to :user
```

When @user is updated, I build a temporal phone to show in the view.

```rb
...
def show
    @user.phones.build(:type => 'default') if @user.phones.size == 0
end
def update
    #get params from view, validate, and save
end
```

In the Haml I have

```
...
- @user.phones.each_with_index do |p, index|
    # inputs for edit existing phones, or if this is the first time, add new one.
```

I have no problems this way, but I need to order the phones by its id, so I have:

```
...
- @user.phones.order('id ASC').each_with_index do |p, index|
    # inputs for edit existing phones, or if this is the first time, add new one.
```

It works fine when an user haves almost one (in database) phone, but if this is the first time adding new phone, input form doesn't show because I use the temporal phone with  `:type` attribute only.

I patch this adding a condition in the view:

```
...
- if @user.phones.size == 0
    #add default inputs
- else
    - @user.phones.order.each_with_index do |p, index|
        # html inputs...
```

and remove temporal phone from controller:

```rb
...
def show
    #@user.phones.build(:type => 'default') if @user.phones.size == 0
end
def update
    #get params from view, validate, and save
end
```

It works fine, but I think there is a better solution. I'm doing it right or not?

pd: models are simplified.

Answer (score 0):

I got a feeling that main problem is in

```
@user.phones.order.each_with_index
```

instead of looping through your phones with each, you just need to refactor your view by extracting partial for phone. And if you need counter inside of your partial, you just need to use collection counter that rails provide for you. Search for word counter [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#structuring-layouts).
After that you can write something like this in your view:

```
= render partial: 'phone/default' if @user.phones.size == 0
= render partial: 'phone/item', collection: @user.phones.order
```

You may even go further and define [to_partial_path](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/rendering-collections-in-rails) method on your phone class and write something like:

```
= render @user.phones.order
```

So, read about partials [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for more detail.

Comment: Yes, problem is in order('somParam ASC'). But I think the problem is not render. The main problem is that order('someParam') is deleting (or hidding for loop) elements without `someParam`. So, my question is there are another methods to order hash?